# Skipping 22 rows when reading CSV in c#

Tags: c#, csv, count

I need skipping the first 22 rows when reading this `CSV file` in `c#`.

[image]

And I have tried this solution for reader only the `row number 23` on the `CSV file` and `count` the `number of columns` in `row 23`:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/public/target.csv"));
int rows = lines.Count();
int columns = lines[0].Split('|').Count();
Response.Write("Rows = " + (rows - 1) + " <br/>Columns = " + columns);        
Response.End();
```

But the return is:

```
Rows = 24 
Columns = 9
```

And not:

```
Rows = 24 
Columns = 6
```

Because the count is on the first line of the `CSV file`.

How to resolve this?

Comment: `lines.Skip(22)`, try searching.

Comment: `columns = lines[22].Split('|').Count();`

Comment: @Hamamelis: thank you now the skiping working, and for me this question is not duplicate I am sorry Mr CodeCaster.

Comment: @Antonio it _is_ a duplicate. That question shows how you can skip a number of elements in a collection, which is exactly what you're asking. That question wants to skip "1", you want to skip "22", but that does not make it _not_ a duplicate.